# Was the amount Vario gave Hill significant?

Tags: goodfellas

IIRC, it was 3 thousand. I do not mean, significant as in "large amount" but in terms of message being conveyed.

Vario hands over the 3K and then says, "Now I have to turn my back on you." And he then turns and walks away. I know that 3K in 1970 or so was more like 12 or 15 thousand today so it is not a useless amount: Enough probably for multiple months' rent and things like that.

But compared to the kind of money Henry Hill had been making (and giving in part to Vario) and his probable expenses as well as the kind of money he would need to start up some business, criminal or legit, it is not very much.

Was the amount actually a way to underline the fact that Vario was done with HH and HH could expect no further help or association with him or the Mob in general?

Answer (score 0):

> Was the amount actually a way to underline the fact that Vario was done with HH and HH could expect no further help or association with him or the Mob in general?

The amount? No, I don't think so.

Although Paulie Vario is, essentially, done with Henry, he does give him **his whole cash bankroll that he is carrying**.

But the other point is true. Vario gives him just what could be considered *pocket change* and that underlines that Vario feels betrayed and is done with Henry.

The amount is not significant other than, in Henry's eyes, it's a paltry sum.

Comment: In Vario's eyes also, right? He could have said, all I have is 3K on me but I will send you more later. But he did not.